# Django Session Variable resetting

Tags: python, django, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a cookie based session in place and I tried to keep data between two pages stored in the session however the data stored in the session variable keeps restting.

An example of this was:

```
At Home page:
request.session['foo'] = []
request.session['foo'].append('bar')
print request.session['foo'] will yield ['bar']

On second page:
print request.session['foo'] will yield []
```

I was wondering why this is the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`request.session['foo'].append('bar')` does not affect session. Only `request.session['...'] = ...`/`del request.session['...']` affect the session.

Try following code.

```
request.session['foo'] = ['bar']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved

> By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session
>   has been modified – that is if any of its dictionary values have been
>   assigned or deleted:
>
> ```
> # Session is modified.
> request.session['foo'] = 'bar'
>
> # Session is modified.
> del request.session['foo']
>
> # Session is modified.
> request.session['foo'] = {}
>
> # Gotcha: Session is NOT modified, because this alters
> # request.session['foo'] instead of request.session.
> request.session['foo']['bar'] = 'baz'
> ```
>
> In the last case of the above example, we can tell the session object
>   explicitly that it has been modified by setting the modified attribute
>   on the session object:
>
> ```
> request.session.modified = True
> ```
>
> ...